# ServiceStack Jsv serializer fails to deserialize Dictionary<DateTime, ___>

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack, servicestack-text

I'm using OrmLite and one of my entities has property of type Dictionary of DateTime and int and it fails to deserialize that property. I found out that this is Jsv serializer problem. I have failing test:

```
[Test]
public void Can_serialize_and_deserialize_Dictionary_with_DateTime_key()
{
    JsConfig.DateHandler = JsonDateHandler.TimestampOffset;
    var expected = new Dictionary<DateTime, int> {{DateTime.Now, 5}};
    var serializedString = TypeSerializer.SerializeToString(expected);
    var actual = TypeSerializer.DeserializeFromString<Dictionary<DateTime, int>>(serializedString);
    Assert.AreEqual(actual.Keys.First().Year, expected.Keys.First().Year);
}
```

Can anyone suggest how this could be fixed? This seems like Jsv format problem in general and not implementation bug. (but I might be wrong)

Comment: The problem is that JSV can't deserialize this {2013-11-19T16:57:33.7901057-05:00:5}. There are too many colons. That's where it gets confused.

Comment: @kampsj Yes. That is probably bug in Jsv serializer. It forgets to escape that date with ""

Answer (score 2):

As workaround before this issue will be fixed in servicestack.text i assigned my own serialization functions for DateTime and DateTime?

```
JsConfig<DateTime>.SerializeFn = DateTimeSerializer.ToShortestXsdDateTimeString;
JsConfig<DateTime?>.SerializeFn = time => time.HasValue ? DateTimeSerializer.ToShortestXsdDateTimeString(time.Value) : null;
```

Those are same functions used inside servicestack.text, but when you assign your own functions library will check if your values needs escaping or not.